# splitting a bitmap into array of bitmaps

Tags: c#, arrays, bitmap

Please read title first. this is main idea
Question is Where's the problem of this C# code?(There's no compile or after running error but doesn't work)
I traced it and found even array of bitmaps are not empty and the class is working properly; but picturebox doesn't show the value of array(bitmap).

**The class**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace GRID
{
    class MasterSplitter
    {
        public BitmapArray_Block[] BMP2Array(Bitmap inp, Point BlockSize)
        {
        if (BlockSize.X > inp.Width || BlockSize.Y > inp.Height)
            BlockSize.X = BlockSize.Y = 100;

        int NW =0, NH = 0;
        int tx =1, ty = 1;
        if (((inp.Width%BlockSize.X) == 0) && ((inp.Height%BlockSize.Y) == 0))
        {
            NW = inp.Width;
            NH = inp.Height;
        }
        else
        {
            tx= inp.Width / BlockSize.X;
            NW = (BlockSize.X*tx) +BlockSize.X;
            ty = inp.Height / BlockSize.Y;
            NH = (BlockSize.Y * ty) + BlockSize.Y; 
        }

        //Operations for making an exact bitmap size
        Bitmap Temp = new Bitmap(NW, NH);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(Temp);
        g.DrawImage(inp, 0, 0, new Rectangle(0,0,Temp.Width, Temp.Height), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        g.Dispose(); //Cleaning up; Temp now has the exact bitmap size of what input BMP should has for devision.

        BitmapArray_Block[] T = new BitmapArray_Block[(tx * ty) + 1]; //Array for Bitmap MatriX

        int Xpos = 0, Ypos;
        int counter =0;
        for (int i=0; i<tx; i++)
        {
            Ypos = 0;
            for (int j=0;j<ty;j++)
            {
                BitmapArray_Block t = new BitmapArray_Block();
                t.start_location = new Point(Xpos,Ypos);
                t.BMP = new Bitmap(BlockSize.X,BlockSize.Y);
                Graphics gt = Graphics.FromImage(t.BMP);
                gt.DrawImage(Temp, Xpos, Ypos, new Rectangle(0, 0, t.BMP.Width, t.BMP.Height), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
                gt.Dispose();
                T[counter] = t;

                Ypos += BlockSize.Y;
                counter+=1;
            }
            Xpos += BlockSize.X;
        }

        return T;
    }



    public class BitmapArray_Block
    {
        public Point start_location;

        public Bitmap BMP;


    }
}
```

**The code for showing the result:**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MasterSplitter M = new MasterSplitter();
    BitmapArray_Block[] T =M.BMP2Array(new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image),new Point(100,100));
    pictureBox1.Image = T[1].BMP;
}
```

Comment: Why are you adding `1` to the array size?

Comment: @Rotem In case of index refining! it's about swapping method, don't mention it.

Comment: You are aware this puts the data in the array by columns, and not by rows? Usually you'll want the x loop inside the y loop. Also, general advice: code like this gets tons mor clear by simply actually calling the loop variables "x" and "y",

Comment: As for your issue... debug these pieces of code and confirm the object is created and inside that BMP property, and retrieved from it.

Comment: Thanks @Nyerguds , As you told I verified that array is filled by bitmap pieces and I traced the variables from the start point to end(code for showing by the pictureBox)

Comment: And about two dimensional arrays; yes usually developers use two dim. arrays but I'm sure you know even two dimensional arrays are saving linear and this makes a little time loose for rearranging the variables and in my project We're talking about More than hundreds pieces of bitmap retrieving from server and replacing them. As you know time and accuracy for manipulating the memory for this amount of data communication between the client and server will be our priority; and this algorithm found after studying the other similar algorithms. Anyway thanks for your advice

Comment: I didn't mention 2-dimensional arrays... I'm just saying that the second element in your array will not be chunk (X1, Y0) as you'd expect, but instead chunk (X0, Y1). That's the block _below_ your top left corner, not the one to the right of it. Admitted, it matters little if you actually use the coordinates stored in the class, but I just thought I'd point that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got the arguments of `DrawImage` wrong. Check the argument descriptions. The `x` and `y` at the start are the coordinates at which to *draw* the image, and the rectangle, unlike in some of the other overloads, specifies the portion of the *original* image that will be drawn.

This means that your current code is always taking the same upper left corner of your source image, and after processing the first block at (0,0), the piece you try to draw will simply be drawn outside the available frame. If you had tested on `T[0].BMP` it would actually have worked, but starting from index 1 all the images will be empty.

The correct code should be this:

```
// "using" will automatically dispose the resource after use, even in case of exceptions.
using(Graphics gt = Graphics.FromImage(t.BMP))
    gt.DrawImage(Temp, 0, 0, new Rectangle(Xpos, Ypos, BlockSize.X, BlockSize.Y), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
```

Comment: + I really appreciate for DrawImage code correction.

Comment: I tested the class after applying your tip; it works 100% successfully. Thank you very much @Nyerguds

Comment: @SM_SOF If the answer helped you, [please upvote and accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).